# Display additional data from view class in XAML at design time in a MVVM(cross) scenario

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, mvvmcross

I'm using a standard MVVMCross setup for a very basic cross platform project. There is a View class and a ViewModel class. Additionally, there is a bunch of data (Strings) which is view-related in a c# class exposed as standard properties.

As far as I have understood, the DataContext of the page is occupied by MVVMCross .

My view (FirstView)is derived from MvxWpfView. Also there is a BaseView class. (think simplest case). I don't want to insert it in the ViewModel (other visual studio project) because it is view data. Is it possible to intercept MVVMCross and dynamically add objects/data? How can I merge view data (not viewmodel) from MyAddonClass into MVVMCross DataContext so it is available in XAML?

Thanks for tips.